# How to fetch contacts from yahoo in iOS

Tags: php, ios, yahoo-api

For yahoo I am using SocialSample app of yahoo. I can login to yahoo account but it redirects me to a url which I am providing as a fallback url in session authorization.

`[self.session sendUserToAuthorizationWithCallbackUrl:@"www.yahoo.com"];`

I have no idea how to redirect from browser to my app. I have searched stackoverflow and there is this link    [How to use Yahoo! contact api in iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056843/how-to-use-yahoo-contact-api-in-ios-application) in which php script is advised to use. But I have no experience in php. So I am unable to understand the whole logic behind this.

Also when I tried to create a project on developer.yahoo.com, it asks me to provide a domain name while I select private access to user.

help me on these issue.